# Adding New Field to Signup Form in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom-field

I was added new field called "How did you get to know about us?" to my Signup From. using following code and it's appeared on Signup Page but when I signup that field doesn't show in the All customers table in admin. That new field doesn't save. How can I fix this ? 
[image]

```
<div class="field required">
   <label for="custom_fieldd" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('How did you get to know about us?') ?></span></label>
   <div class="control">
     <input type="text" name="how_did_found" id="how_did_found" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCustomField()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('How did you get to know about us?') ?>" class="input-text">
   </div>
</div>
```

Then I added the new Attribute as following

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'how_did_found',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'How Did Found',
                'input' => 'text',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'required' => true,
                'default' => '0',
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'system' => false,
                'position' => 1000
            ]
);
        $howdidfound = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'how_did_found');
        $howdidfound->setData(
           'used_in_forms',
            ['customer_register_address']
        );
        $howdidfound->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit your code part to add **adminhtml_customer**:

```
'used_in_forms',
        ['customer_register_address','adminhtml_customer']
```

this will show your field in admin customer information section.

To show column in customer grid you have to add after ('position' => 1000 ) :

```
'is_used_in_grid' => 1,
```

Comment: didn't work. Cant find in Columns

Comment: columns you mean, customer grid ? then you would need to select the field from "Columns" drop down to show.

Comment: yeh. in customer grid. I have update the Question. I have checked in the  "Columns" drop down. Can't find it there

Comment: I have updated my answer, you have to pass  'is_used_in_grid' => 1, in array

Comment: it's still doesn't work

Comment: do you see field on customer form ?

Comment: well the changes you make in installData.php file will not effect unless you upgrade your module version to avoid this you have only option to change value to 1  in "is_visible_in_grid" column of your attribute in database table "customer_eav_attribute"

Comment: yes. its appeared

Comment: to do this task. I have only updated the InstallData.php and register.phtml. is it need more files ?

Comment: To show field in grid and admin you only need installData.php, since you have already created the field using installData script now either you change your module version or change value in customer_eav_attribute table , hope it will work..

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  InstallSchema.php >> add customer attribute

```
/** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
$customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

$setup->startSetup();

$customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'how_did_found', [
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'How Did Found',
    'input' => 'text',
    'frontend_class' => 'validate-url',
    'required' => 0,
    'sort_order' => 110,
    'visible' => 1,
    'system' => 0,
    'position' => 110
]);
//add attribute to attribute set
$attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'how_did_found');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']);
$attribute->save();

$setup->endSetup();
```

Step 2: `customer_account_create.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string"><Vendor>_<Modulename>::form/register.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 3: `regiter.phtml:

```
<?php
/**
 * Create account form template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register
 */
?>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_fields_before')?>
<?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.extra')?>
<form class="form create account form-create-account" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset class="fieldset create info">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Personal Information') ?></span></legend><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getSuccessUrl() ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getErrorUrl() ?>">
        <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')->setObject($block->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($block->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
            <div class="field choice newsletter">
                <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if ($block->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox">
                <label for="is_subscribed" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></span></label>
            </div>
            <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob') ?>
        <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?php echo $_dob->setDate($block->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_taxvat = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat') ?>
        <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?php echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($block->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_gender = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender') ?>
        <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?php echo $_gender->setGender($block->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <!-- Custom code for how-did-found Field -->
        <div class="field how-did-found">
            <label for="how-did-found" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('How Did you found?') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="how_did_found" id="how-did-found" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getData('how_did_found')) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('How Did you found?') ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="250">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End -->

    </fieldset>
    <?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
        <fieldset class="fieldset address">
            <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Address Information') ?></span></legend><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />
            <div class="field company">
                <label for="company" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Company') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Company') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field telephone">
                <label for="telephone" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>

            <div class="field street required">
                <label for="street_1" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street Address') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getStreet(0)) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_streetValidationClass ?>">
                    <div class="nested">
                        <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                        <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                            <div class="field additional">
                                <label class="label" for="street_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_i ?>">
                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Address') ?></span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getStreetLine($_i - 1)) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street Address %1', $_i) ?>" id="street_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_i ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_streetValidationClass ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field required">
                <label for="city" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('City') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('City') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field region required">
                <label for="region_id" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State/Province') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                        <option value=""><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Please select a region, state or province.') ?></option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field zip required">
                <label for="zip" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Zip/Postal Code') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field country required">
                <label for="country" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Country') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <?php echo $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $addressAttributes = $block->getChildBlock('customer_form_address_user_attributes');?>
            <?php if ($addressAttributes): ?>
                <?php $addressAttributes->setEntityType('customer_address'); ?>
                <?php $addressAttributes->setFieldIdFormat('address:%1$s')->setFieldNameFormat('address[%1$s]');?>
                <?php $block->restoreSessionData($addressAttributes->getMetadataForm(), 'address');?>
                <?php echo $addressAttributes->setShowContainer(false)->toHtml()?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
        </fieldset>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign-in Information') ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field required">
            <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field password required" data-mage-init='{"passwordStrengthIndicator": {}}'>
            <label for="password" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Password') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Password') ?>"
                       class="input-text"
                       data-password-min-length="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getMinimumPasswordLength()) ?>"
                       data-password-min-character-sets="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()) ?>"
                       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
                       autocomplete="off">
                <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" >
                    <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Password Strength'); ?>:
                        <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label" >
                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('No Password'); ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="field confirmation required">
            <label for="password-confirmation" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Confirm Password') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Confirm Password') ?>" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info'); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Create an Account') ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Create an Account') ?></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action back" href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Back') ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function($){

    var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
    var ignore = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_dob->isEnabled() ? '\'input[id$="full"]\'' : 'null'; ?>;

    dataForm.mage('validation', {
    <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.prop('id').search('full') !== -1) {
                var dobElement = $(element).parents('.customer-dob'),
                    errorClass = error.prop('class');
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                dobElement.find('.validate-custom').addClass(errorClass)
                    .after('<div class="' + errorClass + '"></div>');
            }
            else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        ignore: ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')'
    <?php else: ?>
        ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
    <?php endif ?>
    }).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

});
</script>
<?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#country": {
            "regionUpdater": {
                "optionalRegionAllowed": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($block->getConfig('general/region/display_all') ? 'true' : 'false'); ?>,
                "regionListId": "#region_id",
                "regionInputId": "#region",
                "postcodeId": "#zip",
                "form": "#form-validate",
                "regionJson": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Directory\Helper\Data')->getRegionJson() ?>,
                "defaultRegion": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormData()->getRegionId() ?>",
                "countriesWithOptionalZip": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Directory\Helper\Data')->getCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Step 4: `customer_account_edit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <!-- Set Custom Template for Register form -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer_edit">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string"><VendorName>_<ModuleName>::form/edit.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <!-- End -->
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 5: `edit.phtml`

```
<?php

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit $block */
?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('\VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Data'); ?>
<form class="form form-edit-account" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl('customer/account/editPost') ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset class="fieldset info">
        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Account Information') ?></span></legend><br>
        <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')->setObject($block->getCustomer())->toHtml() ?>

        <?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob') ?>
        <?php $_taxvat = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat') ?>
        <?php $_gender = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender') ?>
        <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?php echo $_dob->setDate($block->getCustomer()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?php echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($block->getCustomer()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?php echo $_gender->setGender($block->getCustomer()->getGender())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <!-- Custom Code For how-did-found Field -->
        <div class="field" data-container="how-did-found">
            <label class="label" for="how-did-found">
                <span>
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('How Did you found?') ?>
                </span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="how_did_found" id="how-did-found" data-input="how-did-found" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_helper->getCustomerAttributeValue($this->getCustomer()->getId(), 'how_did_found')); ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('How Did you found?') ?>" class="input-text"  maxlength="250"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End -->

        <div class="field choice">
            <input type="checkbox" name="change_email" id="change-email" data-role="change-email" value="1" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change Email') ?>" class="checkbox" />
            <label class="label" for="change-email"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change Email') ?></span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="field choice">
            <input type="checkbox" name="change_password" id="change-password" data-role="change-password" value="1" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change Password') ?>"<?php if ($block->getChangePassword()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
            <label class="label" for="change-password"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change Password') ?></span></label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="fieldset password" data-container="change-email-password">
        <legend class="legend"><span data-title="change-email-password"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change Email and Password') ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field email required" data-container="change-email">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="email" data-input="change-email" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getCustomer()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field password current required">
            <label class="label" for="current-password"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Current Password') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" class="input-text" name="current_password" id="current-password" data-input="current-password" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field new password required" data-container="new-password" data-mage-init='{"passwordStrengthIndicator": {}}'>
            <label class="label" for="password"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('New Password') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password" id="password"
                    data-password-min-length="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getMinimumPasswordLength()) ?>"
                    data-password-min-character-sets="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()) ?>"
                    data-input="new-password"
                    data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
                    autocomplete="off" />
                <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" >
                    <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Password Strength'); ?>:
                        <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label" >
                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('No Password'); ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field confirm password required" data-container="confirm-password">
            <label class="label" for="password-confirmation"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Confirm New Password') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_confirmation" id="password-confirmation"
                    data-input="confirm-password"
                    autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info'); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action save primary" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Save') ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Save') ?></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action back" href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Go back') ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/mage"
    ], function($){
        var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
        var ignore = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_dob->isEnabled() ? '\'input[id$="full"]\'' : 'null'; ?>;

        dataForm.mage('validation', {
        <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.prop('id').search('full') !== -1) {
                    var dobElement = $(element).parents('.customer-dob'),
                        errorClass = error.prop('class');
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                    dobElement.find('.validate-custom').addClass(errorClass)
                        .after('<div class="' + errorClass + '"></div>');
                }
                else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            ignore: ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')'
        <?php else: ?>
            ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
        <?php endif ?>
        });        
    });
</script>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=change-email], [data-role=change-password]": {
            "changeEmailPassword": {
                "titleChangeEmail": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change Email') ?>",
                "titleChangePassword": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change Password') ?>",
                "titleChangeEmailAndPassword": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change Email and Password') ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Step 6: `helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
namespace <Vendorname>\<ModuleName>\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
/**
 * Customer helper for view.
 */
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    protected $_customerFactory;

    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getCustomerAttributeValue($customerId, $attributeCode)
    {
        $media_dir = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                ->getStore()
                ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

        $customerObject = $this->_customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
        return $attribute = ($customerObject->getData($attributeCode)) ? $customerObject->getData($attributeCode): false;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, it didn't work out. it only appear on the form and not appeared in customer grid