# How to add field to sign up Form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, forms

I want to add field name "HOW DID YOU GET TO KNOW ABOUT US?". I can add field in view. But i have no idea how to save this value in database and how to search users by this value. Please advice

Comment: this question is already have been asked, You have to create custom module for creating custom attribute, you can check this post for solution. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203924/adding-new-field-to-signup-form-in-magento-2/203926#203926

Answer (score 1):

If you are a developer, you can follow any of the below links to add custom customer attribute programmatically.

- https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-customer-attribute-programmatically.html
- http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-make-customer-attribute.html
- http://coolblueweb.com/blog/adding-a-customer-attribute-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Else, you can have a look at below modules:

- https://store.webkul.com/Magento2-Custom-Registration-Field.html
- https://github.com/sashas777/magento2-customer-attribute-extension

Please let me know if it solved your problem.